# Performing multiple loops with condition on loop parameters

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a function that I wish to evaluate with respect to three parameters `a_1,a_2,a_3`, where I must have that `a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 1`, and I want to do this for *all* possible combinations where `a_i` can only be multiples of `1/N` for some pre-specified `N`.

I am currently performing this via

```py
import numpy as np

N = 10
iter = 0
something = [0]*N

for a_1 in np.linspace(0,1,N):

   for a_2 in np.linspace(0,1,N):

      if (a_1 + a_2 <= 1)

        a_3 = 1 - (a_2 + a_1)
        something[iter] = some_func(a_1,a_2,a_3)
        iter += 1
```

Although, I was wondering if there is a neater way to do this, that also holds up with regards to performance if say `N` is very large.

Choosing `a_1, a_2, a_3` can be seen as the weights of all possibly subdivisions of the interval `[0,1]` into multiples of units intervals of length `1/N`, and if a nice enough representation exists of all these possibilities, the code could be simplified, where the double for loop could instead be written as a single loop:

```py
...

pos_comb = possible_combinations(0,1,N) # array [[a_1,a_2,a_3],...,[x_1,x_2,x_3]] of size N such that sum(pos_comb[i]) = 1 for any i.

for [a_1,a_2,a_3] in pos_comb
   something[iter] = some_func(a_1,a_2,a_3)
   iter += 1
...
```

This could of course then be extended to the case of an arbitrary number of loops.

I was wondering if the proposed method above is possible?

Comment: `itertools.product` is the function you are looking for. (Strictly speaking, it's a type, not a function.)

Comment: From an efficiency stand point, you won't want to compute the product of the linear space with itself, but with a modified linear space that will guarantee `a_1 + a_2 <= 1`.